# WooCommerce JS issues

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

In my cart and checkout page I get the following errors:

```
(index) : 332 GET https ://bargdvd.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/js-cookie/js.cookie.min.js?ver=2.1.4 404 (Not Found)
woocommerce.min. js ? ver = 3.4 .6 : 1 Uncaught ReferenceError : Cookies is not defined 
GET https ://bargdvd.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/js-cookie/js.cookie.min.js?ver=2.1.4 404 (Not Found)
```

if the s out of the https is removed the links to JS files work, they are all there....but there is an 's' in the http as it's meant to be secure for checkout....any ideas how I can resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: ¿Have you tried to disable "Force Https" on checkout on Woocommerce>>Settings>>Checkout?

Comment: thanks, I can't find where to edit that.... but don't I want to keep it as Https to keep it secure?

Comment: just read this page https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/ssl-and-https/ which says that the option isn't available if website url in general settings is set as https://

Comment: Sorry, I used an old version. The option of Force HTTPS is in Woocommerce>Settings>Advanced. And you also need to check General Settings.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried forcing HTTPS on checkout etc and having rest as HTTP, but no joy, also tried SSL settings plugin... at end of tether :(

Comment: so turns out when I updated Woocommerce, it caused apache log error and triggered mod_sec rules.....has anyone else had similar issues with woocommerce update?